# Most likely & mostly likely & more likely

Tags: gerunds, infinitives

I know that we always use infinitive after more likely but Do we use gerund or inginitive after most likely and mostly likely? If we use both gerund and infinitive please explain what the difference is.

Comment: I think you should expand your question. Especially that "mostly likely" is a very tricky, obscure, rare phrase which most likely doesn't mean what you think it means (it's talking about probabilities of probabilities. )

Answer (score 1):

- 'Most likely' is a *superlative*. It means that nothing else is as likely as this possibility.
- 'More likely' is *comparative*. It means that this is more likely than some other possibility you have previously mentioned.
- 'Mostly likely' doesn't sound right, although I suppose there could be some convoluted contexts where it might be. 'Mostly' is an adverb of *frequency*; it says how often something happens. So, if something is simply 'likely' (possible, liable to happen) then saying 'mostly likely' would, I suppose, mean that it is possible *most of the time*.

Comment: +1 "mostly likely" is rare - see [google ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mostly+likely%2C+most+likely%2C+more+likely&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmostly%20likely%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmost%20likely%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmore%20likely%3B%2Cc0). Most recent attestations seem to be typos or something a proof reader missed. A few seem to at least make some sense: of note: [Adam Smith](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/An_Inquiry_Into_the_Nature_and_Causes_of/rxwUAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22mostly+likely%22&pg=PA279&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: @BillyKerr As I said, it would have to be a convoluted context for it to work. Like 'mostly harmless'. Something either is, or is not harmless.

Comment: Yeah, but you can always trust a philosopher to find a convoluted context!! LOL

Comment: Or should I have said "mostly trust"? ;)

Comment: "When visiting various cities in Brazil, you're mostly likely to get mugged, although there are some safe enough having a fake wallet and a fake phone is not a necessity."